# An error message stating "Can't install [App Name]" appears when installing the apk from the Google Play Store

Tags: android, apk

We have an android application that is meant for several clients and has common features. We therefore have various APKs for each client(white labeled), each with a unique package name and signing key in accordance with Play Store regulations.
There are no problems while uploading to the Play Store, but there are error when downloading and installing, such as "Can't install [App Name]", only while installing above mentioned apps (multiple app's) in a single device. Please provide any relevant solutions.

apk is working fine in case of direct install using ADB

**Error screen**
[image]

Comment: I assume it happens when one app is already being installed right?

Comment: Yes, with different package name

Comment: Its won't make sure that having package name will do the job, I recommend you to install one app and install next via android studio it can give you reason,
I doubt it is due to same content provider or something is colliding in the app, you might want to check all modules etc.

Comment: Have you checked logcat if it shows details on the failed package installation process and the reason?

Comment: Since it's not downloading at all, there won't be a log.